# React/Php/MySQL - send variables two ways via REST API (AJAX)

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs

I am building a web app using a ReactJS front-end, PHP back end with mySQL database.

The app is for a transfer service, and the way I am doing the prices is by assigning each location a number, which references its row or column number in a table.

The numbers corresponding to locations are stored client-side in the JSX code, in the "id" field. So the pickup location options might be:

```
<select className="custom-select" id='suburbOptions' onChange={suburbChoiceListener}>
    <option id="0" value="0"> Please Select Suburb </option>
    <option id="1" value="suburbPicked" title="Manhattan">Manhattan</option>
    <option id="2" value="suburbPicked" title="Brooklyn">Brooklyn</option>
    ...
    ...
</select>
```

And the dropoff might be:

```
<select className="custom-select" id='airportOptions' onChange={airportChoiceListener}>
    <option id="0" value="0"> Please Select Airport </option>
    ...
    ...
    <option id="4" value="suburbPicked" title="JFK">JFK</option>
</select>
```

The price for Manhattan to JFK would be contained in row 1, column 4 of the MySQL table, served with php.

What should happen is the following:

1. Client side sends price codes to server via AJAX method.
2. Based on these codes server retrieves correct price from database via MySQL query.
3. Server returns correct price in response for display on the front end.

I know how to post data to a server via AJAX, and I know how to fetch data from a database via a MySQL Query, but how do I attach data to a response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of possible solutions, but the easiest will be wrapping your array with `json_encode($queryResult)` and outputting it with `echo`. And the last touch would be setting headers, so when js client receives it, it knows it's json.
You could do that with `header('Content-type:application/json')`.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME";
$response = [];

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $response[] = $result;
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}
header('Content-type:application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

After finishing it with pure php, try using frameworks like [Laravel Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com), [Slim Framework](https://www.slimframework.com) or [Symfony](https://symfony.com). (first two were created for purposes like this). Each will do it's job as every each of them are supported by thousands of developers.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I had a look at Slim and it's pretty nifty - sort of like Node.js + Express.